# Enable a button in figureA from figureB - Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

How can I enable a button in figureA, from a figureB?

It is a GUI in Matlab.
FigureA, opens FigureB, and then if user do some staff in FigureB, I want to enable a button in FigureA.

Is this possible?

If not, is there a way to know when FigureA gains again focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating figure B you can pass in its `UserData` a handle to the button in figure A.
In figure B when the appropriate event happens, you can use the handle to the button of figure A stored in `UserData` of figure B to enable the button.

-Shai